# Regex expression to validate a formula

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex and currently building web application in Java.I have the following requirements to validate a formula:

1. Formula must start with “T”
2. A formula can contain the following set of characters:

   - Digit: 0 - 9
   - Alpha: A - Z
   - Operators: *, /, +, -
   - Separator: ;
3. An operator must always be followed by a digit
4. The character “T” must always be followed by a digit or an alpha.
5. The separator must always be followed by “T”.
6. The character “M” must always be followed by an operator.

I manage to build up the following expression as shown below:

```
^[T][A-Z0-9 -- \\+*;]*
```

But i don't know how to add the following validation with regex above:

1. An operator must always be followed by a digit
2. The character “T” must always be followed by a digit or an alpha.
3. The separator must always be followed by “T”
4. The character “M” must always be followed by an operator.

Valid sample: `TA123;T1*2/32M+`

Invalid Sample: `T+qMg;Y`

Comment: what inputs would match these conditions?

Comment: TA123:T+1*2/32M+ - valid

Comment: How can this be valid....after `T` you need `alpha` or `digit`

Comment: Would you not need a digit after the last `+` as well?

Comment: My apologies vks you are right i have already updated my question.Thanks for the quick response

Comment: This would be much easier, if you used multiple regexes: One to check the character set and one or more to check for errors (e.g. T followed by something not an alpha or a digit, M something not a operator). Also: Your "valid" example violates rule 3.

Comment: No parentheses? Strictly speaking a regular expression can't handle nested syntax, but some *implementations* of RE can. You can't use RE to handle operator precedence either. You're almost certainly reaching for the wrong tool here. Have a look around for recursive descent expression parsers, or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Comment: @EJP: This **can** be represented as FSA, so it's possible to represent this as regex too. Why are you talking about nesting and operator precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!.*[*+/-]\\D)(?!.*T\\W)(?!.*[;:][^T])(?!.*M[^*+/-])[T][A-Z0-9 +/*;:-]*$
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/7

Answer (score 0):

We lack a bit of information to fully understand what you want. A couple examples would help.

For now, a small regexp :
    `^(T[A-LN-Z0-9]*M[+-/*][0-9];?)*`

EDIT : 
From my understanding, this should be close to what you're looking for :

`^(T([A-LN-Z0-9]*M?[+\-/*]?[0-9]?)*;?)+`

https://regex101.com/r/hT7aP2/1

This regexp forces the line to begin with a T, then have 0 to many [A-LN-Z0-9] range, meaning all your alphas and digits except M. 
Then it **needs** to have a M followed by an operator in the range of [+-/*] *(pretty much +, -, / and *, except that - and / are special characters so we tell the regexp that we want these characters, and not the meaning they're supposed to have)*. 
Then it continues by one to many digits, and ends by a ";" that might or might not be there.

And everything in the parenthesis can be repeated from 0 to several times

I would have liked examples of what you want to validate... For example, we don't know if the line HAVE to end with a ";"

Depending on what you want, splitting the string you want to validate using the character ";" and validating each of the generated string with that regexp might work